# Variant on a Large-Scale Monty Hall Problem

Tags: probability, recursion, monty-hall

I finally figured out the logic behind the Monty Hall problem and why it works the other day.  Reflecting on other explanations I've seen, I hit upon the commonly provided one where instead of 3 doors there's 100, and after you choose one 98 goats get revealed.

This is a variant of that.

Let's take a set of 100 randomly-generated numbers, and assume that the car is behind the last number in the set.  The rules are as follows:

1. The player chooses a door
2. The host opens the next door on the list
3. If the player's current door gets opened before the last number, he loses immediately.  Otherwise, he has a choice of whether to keep his current door or switch it.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until either the contestant's door is opened or the final door is opened.

Under these conditions, and assuming a truly random distribution of numbers being chosen, does the same principle still hold?  Is it better to shift around every move or to wait for more favorable odds (e.g. perhaps sitting out the first 50 numbers or so)?

**In short: Do the rules of the Monty Hall problem change when recursively opening  the doors and allowing switching instead of jumping to revealing N-2 doors and allowing one switch?**

Comment: Consider $N=3$. It is almost the same as classic Monty Hall, except that with probability 1/3 you immediately lose. If you didn't immediately lose, then the same logic as in classic Monty Hall tells you to switch, because the host will not open the door with the car until the very last stage of the game.

Comment: @Ian: in the classic question, Monty cannot open your initial door whatever is behind it, and this is what leads to the benefit from switching.  In this game he can, so there is no gain (or loss) from switching

Comment: @Henry You're right, I just had to write out the cases. I'm surprised that the restriction that he can't open the car door doesn't do anything. But it's true. If you have doors 1 2 3, and they're opened in that order (but you don't know that), then it goes like this. You pick 1, you lose. You pick 2, if you switch you win, if you don't switch you lose. You pick 3, if you switch you lose, if you don't switch you win. 1/3 chance to win either way, with a 1/2 chance if you condition on not losing immediately. Presumably the general problem is the same as this.

Comment: I guess the reasoning is: in the classic game, if you picked wrong (which you probably did) then switching makes you win. If you picked right (which you probably didn't) then switching makes you lose. But here, if you picked wrong, you might lose before you even get the chance to switch.

Comment: If doors are opened randomly, there is nothing to be gained (or lost) in switching.
If the host has no additional information, then there is no information revealed when the host opens a door and no reason to switch.  The reason that the classic Monty Hall problem says you should switch relies on Monte knowing the location of the car, and you knowing Monty behaves.

Comment: @DougM In this case Monty also knows where the car is and it factors into how he opens doors (he always reveals the car last). Yet there is still no effect.

Comment: Considering it from the other side of the risk vs. reward scale for a moment, does the inherent level of risk go up by staying on a number instead of switching?

Comment: No, the distribution is exactly the same regardless of when you switch, again because of this modification to the original rules that makes it possible for you to instantly lose.